# Creating a website that uses WEB and API routes in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

As I understand it, I could use API routes and build an API for my website's vue components to access data from my database and if I ever went on to build a mobile app (which is 50/50 at this stage), that would use the API too.

If this is the case, how would my website access the data - I presume through web routes, but would you not end up coding the same methods twice?

For example, a simple get users method, you would have one for the API that returned JSON and one for the website that returned a view. Would you have to write (I know it's simple eloquent but anyway...) the get users method twice in two controllers?

Looking for some guidance on basic setup of routes / controllers when using both WEB & API routes.

Comment: You could consider some JS framework that uses API routes too (i.e. VueJs or React) and then you would need just to have API routes with one web route that is not directly responsible for getting data on page but only for serving frontend page. That way you don't duplicate the code but you rather use API code for all client application types (i.e. browser native mobile, API data server etc...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use repository pattern in laravel to avoid adding logics in controller or in models

You can use the repository as data layer and change what you want to pass on ApiUserController or UserController. (Json or Array)

Web routes can also return json though. So using web route for vue and API routes for mobile app is also an option

Or you can use just API routes for both.

Depends on use case

## **Repository Pattern Article**

https://itnext.io/repository-design-pattern-done-right-in-laravel-d177b5fa75d4